# How do I delegate the textStorageDidProcessEditing notification?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos, delegates

I try to make it as short as possible, please don't get me wrong if I provide not enough information:

I got a NSTextView in a document-based cocoa application which is the result of [a tutorial by Apple for programming a text editor within 15 minutes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextArchitecture/Tasks/TextEditor.html). In my "PureBasicDocument.m" implementation I got the textDidChange method which is called every time I change something in the NSTextView. I also got the method for the textStorageDidProcessEditing notification, but it is never called. How do I invoke it? I am sure I simply just forgot to assign outlets or something like that. But staring and looking over and over again at the textView and the window for their outlets did not bring me further. I am clueless. Better than nothing, here's at least the header file ("PureBasicDocument.h") of my document class for now:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface PureBasicDocument : NSDocument {
    IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
    NSAttributedString *mString;
}

- (NSAttributedString *) string;
- (void) setString: (NSAttributedString *) value;
- (void) textDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification;
- (void) textStorageDidProcessEditing: (NSNotification *) notification;

@end
```

I apologize again if I did not use the "delegate" (and further) expressions right, I am still completely new to Objective-C and programming on a Mac in general.

Answer (score 1):

right click the pureBasicDocument Object  in the MainMenu.xib.You can see the outlets(textView).
from there you can make the connection to the respective tableview.
make sure whether you have include the delegate

Comment: My NSTextView is connected as a delegate under "Referencing Outlets". Under "Outlets" I have a textView and a window where only the window is connected. Connecting the textView in that does not has any effect.

PS: I don't have any tableView - only a Scroll View which cannot be connected.

As far as I understood I also need to make a delegate of the NSTextStorage which is contained by the NSTextView and not the NSTextView itself.